# Can't seem to read the FirebaseDB data on App-Inventor

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, app-inventor

I'm creating a registration to an app that I'm developing but I can't seem to read the information I'm storing on my firebaseDB.

My rules on the firebase are already

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
```

I've tried some youtube tutorials but even after doing the exact same thing it didn't work.

[image: Image of my app code]